# Product scoped dimensions in Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, data-layer

I need to pass my product scoped custom dimension throught Google Tag Manager into Google Analytics. I am able to read just first variable in my array of objects of products. And no custom dimension is showing at all (even this first value of all of them) in my Analytics.

I have set custom dimension in Analytics as product scoped:
[image]

Then in GTM I seted up custom dimension in my tag.
[image]

In dimension value I used variable which goes into structure and find variable productSize.

[image]

And here is my code:

```
<script>
    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'productImpression',
      'ecommerce': {
        'impressions': [
         {
           'name': 'Android tričko',
           'id': '12345',
           'price': '299',
           'brand': 'Google',
           'category': 'Pánská trička',
           'variant': 'bílá',
           'list': 'Search Results',
           'productSize': 'L',          // product scoped custom dimension
           'position': 1            
         },
         {
           'name': 'Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt',
           'id': '67890',
           'price': '33.75',
           'brand': 'Google',
           'category': 'Apparel',
           'variant': 'Black',
           'list': 'Search Results',
           'productSize': 'XL',         // product scoped custom dimension
           'position': 2
         }]
      }
    });
</script>
```

As I said the problem is I can read only the first value (obviously) of my custom dimension ("L"). What should I write instead of zero symbol in variable dot notation to get all of the values ("L", "XL")?

I need to pass all values about every products into Analytics. Do I have to I push every product in separate dataLayer.push()? Where is the problem that I don't see anything at all in Analytics? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the name you've given to the dimension via the interface. You'd have to use the ["dimension" keyword plus the numeric index](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#collection) (order of creation), so the dimension that is referred to as "productSize" in the reports would in your example be addressed as "dimension1" in the code:

```
...
'list': 'Search Results',
'dimension1': 'L',          // product scoped custom dimension
'position': 1       
...
```

After that GA will pick your dimensions automatically from the datalayer.

Comment: I've read about this but I thought it doesn't count when I use Tag Manager. Do I have to set something else anywhere in GTM or I just have to hard code dimensions and set them in Analytics?

Comment: You do not have to add anything in GTM, but in my experience processing time until custom dimension show up is a  bit longer that for pageview data. So maybe you just have to wait a few hours more.

Comment: still no change... I am desparate... maybe I am just looking in to wrong place in Google Analytics...

Comment: Where are you looking ? Custom Dimensions do not show up in standard reports, you'd have to set a secondary dimension on your product reports or create a custom report.

Comment: Okay I managed to see product scope custom dimension BUT after I pushed transaction. I still can't see it for product impression and also for another hit scope dimension. But the point is it's working :-). 

Thank you for your help. I will mark your answer as a helpful.

Comment: Hit scope dimensions are working with my own names (via GTM) so I don't have to name it like "dimension1" etc. But product scoped seems to they need this naming convections because I didn't found any way how to dynamicaly find their values and set them in GTM..